# Obj-C, sqlite Commit Transaction, can use Selects within a transaction?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I'm improving the performance of queries in my app, I have several functions where I purely do inserts / updates, which adding begin / commit has greatly improved the speed.

However, my main function which runs when the app starts up, has conditional inserts / updates and selects, based on each other.

My worry is that I'll begin transaction, insert some data into table X conditionally, then select on table X, the query wouldn't find any the data, until commit transaction, I'm correct in my concern ?

As a workaround can I do my inserts / updates with begin / commit, then do my select, then do further transaction within begin / commit ?

PLEASE don't tell me to use FMDB or core data, I'm committed to this path, to provide some fixes.

Comment: I think you are right to worry, however I will be able to tell more if you paste the code of the *main function which runs when the app starts*. Btw. FMDB supports transactions, but if you're having fun using SQLite directly, I will not tell you to use it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> y worry is that I'll begin transaction, insert some data into table X conditionally, then select on table X, the query wouldn't find any the data, until commit transaction, I'm correct in my concern ?

No.  As the documentation for [BEGIN TRANSACTION](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) states, updates and inserts are always done in a transaction, so you would already be seeing this problem if it existed.  This assumes, of course, that all of your SQL statements are being done with the same database connection.

Comment: Just to clarify 100%, if I put begin at the top of my function and commit at the bottom, I'll get the same expected behaviour but better performance ?

Comment: @Bill Thomas: I can't comment on the performance, you need to measure it to answer that part of the question, but the functionality should be OK.